# why it displays the first option by default when adding a new option into select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Fisrt of all, the value of select is null(no option is selected) and there already exist some options. However, it changes to the value of first option after adding a new option into select through jquery and vue respectively, why? (we tested this case on chrome)

1.

```
<select>
    <option val="a">a</option>
    <option val="b">b</option>
<select>
```

at this time:

```
$("select").val() == null
```

2. add an option into select with jquery`$("select").append("<option value='hi'>hi</option>")`

at this time:

```
$("select").val() == "a"
```

Comment: Show your code... We are not as psychic as we will be in the future :)

Comment: I think that is default behavior of the select. You could add an option with  `value="0"` and test for `$('select').val() == 0`

Comment: @gonecoding sorry about that, already add some code by now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, HTML prefers to have an option selected. It is likely that you manually set the `selectedIndex` to `-1` for your `select` which is overridden after appending an element to the select. You have one of two options:

1. Detect your current `selectedIndex` and restore it after appending. Something along to lines of `var originalSelectedIndex = $("select").prop("selectedIndex"); $("select").append("<option value='...'>...</option>"); $("select").prop("selectedIndex", originalSelectedIndex);`.
2. Create an initial element with an empty label such as `<option label=" "></option>` which would in essence submit an empty value to your server upon submit.

Comment: Appending an option *does not* affect the current selection. It is purely because there was no default option: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5dr90fm7/

Comment: The point is that the original post specifically was setting the `selectedIndex` to `-1`, hence by appending an option caused the `<select>` to choose the first item.

Comment: Who's original post? Not the OP here (they only have one question and no history of selectedIndex = -1 anyway). It would be `null` by default and any nomatch value will select the first entry (if a default one is not present). Also a label is not required as you state in the second part.

Comment: The OP's code with the two options listed would not return `null` by default. Since the value being returned initially is `null`, the only way that would have occurred is if the OP specifically set `selectedIndex` to `-1`. Hence by appending an option *it does* affect the current selection.

Comment: I have kindly forked your (Gone Coding) version of the code to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/qhbcqhaf/